# Where is a good/interesting place to go outside of (but not too far) from Osaka? Looking for an overnight trip

Tags: japan, osaka

I will be in Osaka for 8 days and everywhere is booked out for the last weekend. Thought I might head out of the city so I am looking for something a little different and not ridiculously expensive - any ideas?

Ok, the revision. 
where would you like to have experienced/visited in the Kansei area/prefecture if you were only there for a weekend?

Comment: Are you looking for sightseeing or accommodation? Or both?

Comment: Wikivoyage's article on [Osaka](https://en.m.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Osaka) has a "Go Next" section which may be useful.

Comment: Both http://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano

Answer (score 2):

Go to Shirakawago.  Not a short trip, train to Takayama then bus from there to Shirakawago, but it is a cool little village the steep pitched thatched roofs and historic minshukus.  Totally different from Osaka.

Answer (score 2):

Kyoto has many places to visit, and is less than an hour by train from Osaka.  There are many smaller hotels and ryokan there.